# How to make the example to change the elements of a list in R work?

Tags: r

ChatGtp (and other sources) tell me that the code below will allow me to do this. It fails (please see below) even when run from git bash with:

"/c/Program Files/R/R-4.3.1/bin/x64/Rscript.exe" mutate_list.R

```
# Define a function that mutates a list
mutateList <- function(myList) {
     # Modify the list inside the function
     myList$element1 <- "New Value"
     myList$element2 <- 100
 }
 
 # Create a list
 myList <- list(element1 = "Old Value", element2 = 42)
 
 # Call the function to mutate the list
 mutateList(myList)
 
 # Print the modified list
 print(myList)
$element1
[1] "Old Value"

$element2
[1] 42
```

Session info:

```
R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.3 tools_4.2.3
```

Comment: 1) You're not returning the list inside your function.  2) You're not assigning the output when you call your function (R does not (generally) modify in place). 3) The builtin function `modifyList()` does what it seems you're trying to achieve.

Comment: i have poor vision. thanks to whoever edited the question.

Comment: thanks for the modify_list().  i was unaware that most of the objects in r are immutable.

Comment: The objects are not immutable. Its just that R only passes by value. Actually almost all objects in R are mutable. If you want to pass by reference/pointer to do inplace replacement, consider using `R.oo` `proto` `Rcpp` packages. Otherwise you will have to copy the objects mutate them and return completely new objects that are in no way associated with the original objects.

Comment: looks like i need to put my instance variables in a data frame.